# Why does the Maven command "mvn sonar:sonar" work without any plugin configuration in my "pom.xml"?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, maven-plugin

I have a Maven web project in my repo.

I am a Maven noob but still I understand the fact that there are plugins which we need to configure only then we could run plugin specific commands.

**Facts:**

I have a sonar server running on my local machine at port 9000.

I have not added any sonar specific plugin in my POM.xml

**Reference:**

http://www.sonarsource.org/we-had-a-dream-mvn-sonarsonar/

**Observation:**

But still when I run `mvn sonar:sonar` in my project from command line it works fine.

Matter of the fact is **I have NOT configured sonar plugin in my POM.xml Even then from where the hell Maven is picking up and understanding "sonar:sonar" goal/command?**

**Question / curiosity:**

I don't want the working knowledge of sonar itself. I want to know why `mvn sonar:sonar` works without configuring a sonar plugin in my pom.xml

WHY and how?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The reason is that the Sonar Maven Plugin is hosted at the [Codehaus Mojo project](http://mojo.codehaus.org/) and benefits from the groupId "org.codehaus.mojo". This allows to use the shortcut "sonar:sonar" instead of "org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin::sonar" (see the section "Configuring Maven to Search for Plugins" of the [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html))

Comment: Still don't get it.. Why does having the groupId "org.codehaus.mojo" let us use the shortcut?

Comment: @levgen org.apache.maven.plugins and org.codehaus.mojo are special group ids. See the last section of http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html

Comment: This does not answer the question as to how `mvn sonar:sonar` executes while the plugin is not mentioned in pom ? I think the OP did not wanted to ask about how `sonar` is resolved.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin your question seems to be about Maven itself, but not about SonarQube.

Answer (score 5):

Sonar has its own set of plugins (e.g. maven-checkstyle-plugin) which it is running when being invoked. These plugins are automatically configured according to your project settings in your configured Sonar server.

The reasoning behind this to have a controlled configuration in your sonar instance.

The reason it is working automatically for you is that you are using the default values for your sonar server installation (localhost:9000).

This 'zero-configuration' approach is further detailed here: [We had a dream : mvn sonar:sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/we-had-a-dream-mvn-sonarsonar/)

Comment: No, Sonar directly executes the code analyzers like Checkstyle, PMD and Findbugs, without depending on the related Maven plugins. It allows to support non-Maven environments. 
Moreover for information Sonar embeds its own enhanced code analyzer.

Comment: Thanks for setting this straight Simon.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but my assumption is that this capability typically comes from your `settings.xml` instead of our `pom.xml` file with Maven. I would assume that the `<id>sonar</id>` section specifies the name of the profile invoked when running `mvn`.

This is merely a guess as opposed to a definitive answer at this time as other answers seemed to be missing the mark and I don't have the time to dig into the real answers myself at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but my assumption is that this capability typically comes from your `settings.xml` instead of our `pom.xml` file with Maven. I would assume that the `<id>sonar</id>` section specifies the name of the profile invoked when running `mvn`.

This is merely a guess as opposed to a definitive answer at this time as other answers seemed to be missing the mark and I don't have the time to dig into the real answers myself at the moment.

References:

- https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/

Answer (score 0):

As per this page - https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/

Maven project scanner uses the SonarScanner by default. So it works without any set up.